# ValidationSummary component in Flex Framework

Tags: apache-flex, validation

Is there any component that does handle validation errors similarly to ASP.NET's ValidationSummary control in flex? (See screenshot)

[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/ms972961.pdc_userinput_fig2(en-us,MSDN.10).gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/ms972961.pdc_userinput_fig2(en-us,MSDN.10).gif)

Component should really only display all the errors for the validator it watches.

I'm convinced I already used it but I was unable to find it anywhere in the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I achieved the results I was expecting with a bit of work.

Sharing in the event that somebody has the same needs that I had ;-):

- Made a component that overrides validationResultHandler and manages validation errors
- Made sure that all the validators that had to be shown in the component had their listener property set to the component's instance

And thats pretty much it.

```
<my:ValidationView id="vv" />

<mx:StringValidator listener="{vv}" ... />
<mx:Validator listener="{vv}" ... />
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no component in Flex specifically designed to show a collection of all the validation errors in a form. Some built-in components have support for validation error indicators. TextInput, for instance, can display a red border with an error tooltip that appears on mouse roll over.

Comment: I'll guess that i'll just have to write some kind of component for my own needs

Answer (score 1):

Flex Validators work a bit differently than this but check out the [Validator Samples](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex/web/#docIndex=0;illustIndex=0;sampleId=8000) in [Tour de Flex](http://flex.org/tour).

Comment: Yes, I know that they work differently than ASP's ones but my question is more if a component exists for my particular need.

Comment: Flex is very flexible when it comes to validators - you can call validators however you want, handle the results however you want, and even create your own custom validation.

Comment: I'm only trying to not to make a component for something that the framework already has. It seemed that my question wasn't clear enough.